# Flatten data from an object with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, vue.js, ecmascript-6

In my Vue project, I'm doing an API call to my Laravel (nova) backend, the data is returned as follows.

As you can see the data is an **array, which contains an array of objects**. Each array represents a *record*, while each object represents a *field* in that record.

There is the possibility that a record has unnecessary data.

```
const data = [
    [
        {
            attribute: 'id',
            value: 1,
            extra: "not needed data"
        },
        {
            attribute: 'title',
            value: 'The Title',
            extra: "not needed data"
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            attribute: 'id',
            value: 2
        },
        {
            attribute: 'title',
            value: 'The Other Title'
        },
    ],
]
```

I'm wondering how I can use Javascript to flatten this out so it becomes

```
const data = [
    {id: 1, title: 'The Title'},
    {id: 2, title: 'The Other Title'}
]
```

#### What I've tried

I've tried using a combination of map and filter, but the results don't even come close.

Comment: Your input's syntax is not valid. Your desired output's isn't either, actually

Comment: so is the output syntax, also post the code you have tried

Comment: Hmh I notice it's invalid but I don't see how.. What am I missing? An object can contain arrays, right?

Comment: _"I've tried using a combination of map and filter..."_ - You've missed to post this part as well

Comment: Yes @Notflip, but it's required to have keys for its values. Just change the outer braces to square brackets `[]` and it's fine

Comment: Aah I see. Thank you @JackBashford

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `map` with `reduce`, to build an object using only the attribute and value, ignoring all other properties:

```js
const data = [
    [
        {
            attribute: 'id',
            value: 1,
            extra: "not needed data"
        },
        {
            attribute: 'title',
            value: 'The Title',
            extra: "not needed data"
        },
    ],
    [
        {
            attribute: 'id',
            value: 2
        },
        {
            attribute: 'title',
            value: 'The Other Title'
        },
    ],
]

console.log(data.map(a => a.reduce((a, o) => (a[o.attribute] = o.value, a), {})))
```

Comment: That's it Kobe! I always wonder how people can think of things like that, I feel like my brain can't understand reduce, or complex maps.. Thanks!

Comment: @Notflip No worries mate, I've only really just started to get good at using them. If you take time to fully understand how it works, it's a very nice tool to use for data manipulation. If you ever need more help, feel free to ask 